# Install yum packages based on regular expression

Tags: yum, regular-expressions

I would like to install a batch of openoffice.org-* packages from the yum repository.  The catch is that I want to exclude the dozens of openoffice.org-langpack* files when I do it.  I also don't want to have to run two commands (i.e. `yum install openoffice.org-*;yum remove openoffice.org-lang*`).  I've attempted to run the command `yum install openoffice.org-[^l].*` without any luck, as it looks for a package labeled exactly as typed.  What command can I run to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few problems that can't be solved with a healthy dose of awk-fu:

```
yum list | awk '$1 ~ /^openoffice\.org-[^l].*$/ { print $1 }' | xargs yum install
```

Comment: Once it gets to the prompt stating `Is this ok[y/N]:` it exits with `Exiting on user Command`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, yes, good point.  This happens because you're using it on a pipe or from xargs.  One of those.  Do a 'yum install -y' instead.  _Note: it will not prompt you to continue._

Comment: Perfect!  If you don't mind me asking, I am a little familiar with awk, yet not enough to accomplish this, what is the `$1 ~` accomplish?

Comment: Awk breaks up fields into variables using whitespace by default (far more intelligently than `cut` for example).  If you look at the output of `yum list`, the left "field" is the list of packages (installed or available).  So we're doing a regular expression match of field 1 (using the ~ operator) and then performing an action when a line matches.  In this case, we're simply `print`ing a line that contains the first field.  Everything in awk is based on running matches against each input line and performing actions.